# Spring Android mapping not working to pojo

Tags: android, spring

I am getting a `JSON`:

```
[{"LocationId":1,"LocationCode":"Area A"},{"LocationId":2,"LocationCode":"Area B"}]
```

from a web api in android app using spring but its failing to map to a POJO:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DataLocation {
    private String LocationId;
    private String LocationCode;

    public  String getLocationId(){
        return LocationId;
    }
    public  String getLocationCode(){
        return  LocationCode;
    }
}
```

This is the code that gets `json`:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
ResponseEntity<DataLocation[]> forNow = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, DataLocation[].class);
```

[image]

Anyone know why its failing to map?

**EDIT**

this [link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) helped to create a `pojo` that can be converted to `json` via `spring`. So the resultant `POJO` must look like this:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "LocationId",
        "LocationCode"
})
public class DataLocation {

    @JsonProperty("LocationId")
    private Integer locationId;
    @JsonProperty("LocationCode")
    private String locationCode;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonProperty("LocationId")
    public Integer getLocationId() {
        return locationId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("LocationId")
    public void setLocationId(Integer locationId) {
        this.locationId = locationId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("LocationCode")
    public String getLocationCode() {
        return locationCode;
    }

    @JsonProperty("LocationCode")
    public void setLocationCode(String locationCode) {
        this.locationCode = locationCode;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

Comment: How did you try to generate your pojo? I was able to generate one [here](http://jsonschema2pojo.org)

Comment: GSON is better to parse json into POJO try it.

Comment: so i am going to get a `List<GSON>` then convert it to `List<POJO>`

Comment: @MacLeanSochor, i tried the link, thank you it worked. See my edit, you can add it as an aswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are curious, the reason why is probably because it is a very bad practice to capitalize the name of your fields like that.

Usually, if the JSON provided is in a standard camelCase, kebab-case, snake_case, Spring will be able to handle those mappings.

For the odd cases where it can't @JsonProperty is a very handy tool, especially when you need to convert odd values in a setter, etc.